# How to find particular solution to a linear non-homogeneous 2nd order ODE where the Wronskian is equal to $0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a method to find out the particular solution to a non-homogeneous 2nd order ODE where the Wronskian is equal to $0,$ and I already know the general solution (i.e. the fundamental solutions are linearly dependent)?

The following is the ODE:
$$x^2y'' -2xy' + 2y = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

My fundamental solutions were $y=x^2$ and $y=x$

Edit: I realise that the Wronskian does not equal to $0$ but how would I continue with the problem? I do not see a function that I could use to guess the particular solution - I'm guessing I have to use variation of parameters?

Comment: The Wronskian of fundamental solutions cannot be zero if they are independent

Comment: Maybe you made a msitake when you calculated the Wronskian ?

Comment: @Moo I've added the ODE

Comment: @enzotib I've said that the fundamental solutions are linearly dependent

Comment: @Aryadeva yikes I think I might've forgotten to bring the two down when doing the derivative for $ax^2$ 

Comment: @J.Cricks sorry, I misread, but this means that at least one of them is not fundamental

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2y'' -2xy' + 2y = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$y'' -2\left (\dfrac {y}{x} \right)' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$\left(y' -2\dfrac {y}{x} \right)' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
The differential equation is equivalent to:
$$\left (\dfrac {y}{x} \right)'' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
You can integrate.

---

With variation of parameters method:

The solution to the homogeneous DE is:
$$\left (\dfrac {y}{x} \right)''=0 \implies y_h=c_1x^2+c_2x$$
And the Wronskian is:
$$W=\left |\pmatrix { x & x^2 \\ 1 & 2x }\right | = x^2 \ne 0$$